# Select from multiple tables to obtain a single random row

Tags: mysql, select, union

I have this query that goes through my initial `people` table and selects a random row :

```
SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1
```

The thing is, my system has changed a little bit and I currently need to do this query on **multiple tables** (two, at the moment)... but still obtain the same result : **a single, random row**.

I naturally wanted to try the following but I read that it would end up as a Cartesian Product:

```
SELECT * FROM people, products ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1
```

I think I could solve my problem by using `UNION` but couldn't figure out how.

I also have to precise that `people` and `products` have the exact same structure (3 fields) :

- id
- name
- description

Any idea how I could manage to do this query ? Some advice on optimizing it would also be great.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does people and products have same no.of fields ?

Comment: They do, thanks for pointing that out, I'll add it to the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a union?

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1
) AS foo ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1
```

Get one random row from each table, then randomly pick one of THOSE rows as the final result. Of course, this presumes that both tables have the same fields/structure. You might have to do some finessing, like

```
   SELECT 'people' as source_table, id FROM people ...
   UNION
   SELECT 'products', id FROM products
```

Comment: multiple limits in union query are not allowed unless each query with limit is enclosed in () like `(query limit) union (query limit)`

Comment: Thanks! I have a question though, why do you use "AS foo" in this particular case?

Comment: tables derived from subqueries must have an alias assigned to them.

Comment: I see, thanks for your help. I tried using this request right away with PDO, it generated an error (Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY). I added some parenthesis around the queries before and after UNION ALL, it worked perfectly.

Comment: I'm wondering now, would there be a simple way to make this request exclude the previously selected row? In order to prevent the same row to eventually show up twice.